# Can I read objects from file like if it was an array?

Tags: java, file

I have a file, ***example.dat***, in which I stored different Objects, let's say 10 instances of the class "Example".
Now, at a given time, I need to read a specific Example object, let's say I first read the 5th, then the 3rd, then the 8th etc. Basically, I want to read from that file as if it was an Array. Is any way to achieve that?
For now I have:

```
public static Example loadExampleFromFile(int index){
        ObjectInputStream exampleStream = null;
        try{
               exampleStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Example.dat"));

               //Now I should point in the file at the beginning of the Example object 
               //which is the index-th object stored into the file

               return (Example) exampleStream.readObject();
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve that without having to iterate on the whole file every time? 
Hope this is clear.

Comment: The answer really depends on the kind of object you have to store in the file, and how they are stored. If you can store objects (i.e. records) as fixed-sized blocks of data, then it's easy to access the file randomly. Otherwise, you have either to read the file sequentially, or build an index (which is an auxiliary file, pointing to the beginning of records).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut no, it has not a fixed size. I'm gonna look into the second suggestion, if you have any examples I would love to look into them.

Comment: The idea is simple: when you write the file, before writing an object, write the file pointer in the index file, in a fixed-size record (for instance a 32-bit integer). That way, if you want the nth object in your array, just look up the integer at position 4*n in the index (32 bits = 4 bytes). That will tell you were the object lies in the data file. (using the next integer in the index, you even have the object size)

Answer (score 0):

In java, an array is an Object. Can't you store an array and then just use:

`Example[] exampleArray = (Example[]) exampleStream.readObject();`

and then

`exampleArray[index]`

Comment: What if one object fits in RAM, but not the whole array? Or even if it fits, are you gong to read megabytes of data just to pick one or two items?

Comment: As @Jean-ClaudeArbaut said, I don't want to load and have the whole file content in memory. At any time, I'm gonna immediately need just something like 5 out of 200-300 of those items.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't see why my method would take up more space than storing each instance individually and I also don't see why the space left could be a problem. A few hundred Bytes isn't that much. And you only have to load the file once, at the beginning of the program. Then you can store the array and access it when needed.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Who said thet occupy a few hundred bytes? If true, you approach is sensible. In general however it's not (for instance the last dataset I had to handle had rows of ~1kb, for a total of ~25 gb, try to deal with this with your approach). If you really don't see why an array is larger than one of its elements, there is a problem.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut When I answered, I assumed that every Object would be used at some point. But now (bc of OP's comment) I know that only ~5 Object will be loaded. Also, I assumed that we were dealing with much smaller sizes. I'm a hobby programmer, I don't have to deal with Gigabytes of files.. Now I agree with what you said in your idea, which you've presented in a comment to the question.

Comment: Fine. Just to clarify: even if you will need to read the whole file eventually, sometimes you have no other choice but to read and process only a small part at a time (sometimes it doesn't even fit on one disk, and you have to rely on distributed computing).